# Logitech webcam and scarlett 2i2 audio cannot be used together?

Tags: audio, video, webcam, microphone, audio-recording

It seems that my new computer is having trouble recording video from my logitech c290 webcam while recording audio from my microphone plugged into a scarlett 2i2 audio interface. This is weird because it worked on my old computer, which I upgraded to windows 10, so the operating system shouldn't be the issue.

I have tried several video recording applications. Logitechs webcam manager as well as windows camera app record from the webcam microphone. In the logitech software, I have it set to record from scarelett 2i2, and the camera app doesnt give me the option to change recording source, although scarlett 2i2 is set as default. In cyberlink youcam as well as the free version of microsoft expression encoder 4, when the webcam and scarlett 2i2 are selected together in the settings, it give an error and clears the settings.

The audio records fine into Abelton, and video records fine if I don't use scarlett 2i2 as the audio recording source. Also, having the same problem with multiple programs, to me, rules out that it is a problem with any one program.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Any one have any ideas?

Comment: tried reinstalling both drivers. I noticed that i could download a UVC (or something like that) driver as an alternative to the logitech driver. This solved the problem of getting the error, however I'm still getting no audio in the recording unless it is through abelton. microsoft expression even shows that it knows audio is coming in, but for some reason doesn't record it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently uninstalling the scarlett 2i2 drivers from the windows device manager doesnt actually work. I tried it a second time, and noticed that when i restarted my computer, they were there again without me installing them. If you go to program files/focusrite or whatever and used their uninstall executable, that will ACTUALLY uninstall it. After doing that and reinstalling it it's working now.